# The point C has coordinates (2,k) and the distance from A to C is 5. Find the 2 possible values of the constant k

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

The coordinates of A are (6, -2)
I have managed to do every other question in this section but this one, my brother tried to help but just drew a graph and the answers without explaining it, i dont understand the technique behind it? thanks for your help

Comment: Are you familiar with the distance formula?

Comment: square root around (y1-y2)squared + (x1-x2)squared..? then yes but you end up with a k squared minus a k

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: By the Distance Formula, or equivalently by the Pythagorean Theorem,
$$\sqrt{(2-6)^2+(k-(-2))^2}=5.$$
Square both sides and simplify. You will get a quadratic equation in $k$. Solve.
To solve, you can use the Quadratic Formula, or note that the resulting quadratic factors nicely.

Comment: i have managed to get to k squared + k = 5/4

Comment: I get, after simplifying, the equation $k^2+4k-5=0$.

Comment: omg thankyou! i see what to do now! x